# Concavity and $y = (5-x)/(x+3)$

Tags: calculus

$y = (5-x)/(x+3)$

So I need to find where the graph of the function is concave up and concave down. I know you need to find $f"(x)$, but I do not know what to do with it.

Also ____ is dominant as x goes to positive and negative infinity.

Comment: ok, so that is the double prime, what do I do with that to get concavity

Comment: Use the Quotient Rule. Your second derivative is not right. Another way is to note that our function is $-1+\frac{8}{x+3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f''(x) > 0$ means the function is concave up (or convex), $f′′(x) < 0$ means it's concave down (or just concave). If you have an equation for $f''(x)$, you just have to solve one of above-mentioned inequations to get the answer.

Comment: What about dominance?

Comment: @CalcStudent could you please specify the question concerning dominance? What does '______' mean in your initial post? Should some expression be entered there?

Comment: @CalcStudent I believe you have to write $f(x)$ as the sum of two terms and look which term the function tends to as $x \to +\infty$ and $x \to -\infty$